# Compare guarantees for insert with hint for ordered associative containers

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, containers, associative

I want to insert new (unique) element into known place (generally somewhere in the middle) of an ordered associative container `std::set`/`std::multiset`/`std::map`/`std::multimap` using `insert` (w/ hint) or `emplace_hint`.

During insertion operation I absolutely sure, that the place to insert is right before the "hint" iterator. Generally I can compare any two non-neighbouring elements in the container, but this operation is strongly heavyweight. To avoid overhead imposed, I provide custom comparator for the container, which contains a references to pointers to both neigbouring elements (they always became known right before the insertion/emplacement operation).

```
#include <map>
#include <set>

static std::size_t counter = 0;

template< typename T >
struct less
{ 

    T const * const & pl;
    T const * const & pr;

    bool operator () (T const & l, T const & r) const
    {
        if (&l == &r) {
            return false;
        }
        if (pl) {
            if (&l == pl) {
                return true;
            } 
            if (&r == pl) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (pr) {
            if (&r == pr) {
                return true;
            }
            if (&l == pr) {
                return false;
            }   
        }
        ++counter;
        return l < r; // very expensive, it is desirable this line to be unrecheable
    }

};

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    using T = int;
    T const * pl = nullptr;
    T const * pr = nullptr;
    less< T > less_{pl, pr};
    std::set< T, less< T > > s{less_};
    s.insert({1, 2,/* 3, */4, 5});
    std::copy(std::cbegin(s), std::cend(s), std::ostream_iterator< T >(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
    auto const hint = s.find(4);
    // now I want to insert 3 right before 4 (and, of course, after 2)
    pl = &*std::prev(hint); // prepare comparator to make a cheap insertion
    pr = &*hint;
    // if hint == std::end(s), then pr = nullptr
    // else if hint == std::begin(s), then pl = nullptr
    // if I tried to insert w/o hint, then pl = pr = nullptr;
    {
        std::size_t const c = counter;
        s.insert(hint, 3);
        assert(counter == c);
    }
    std::copy(std::cbegin(s), std::cend(s), std::ostream_iterator< T >(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Current *libc++*/*libstdc++* implementations allows me to use described comparator, but is there undefined behaviour if I rely on their current behaviour? Can I rely, that `insert` (w/ hint parameter) or `emplace_hint` (and modern `insert_or_assign`/`try_emplace` w/ hint parameter for `map`/`multimap`) don't touch any other elements other then pointed by `pl` and `pr`? Is it implementation-defined thing?

Why I want this strange thing? IRL I tried to implement *Fortune's algorithm* to find *Voronoi diagram* on the plane using native STL's self-balanced binary search tries. `std::set` is used to store current state of a part of a so-called *beach line*: a chain of sorted *endpoints*. When I add a new *endpoint* I always know the place where to insert it right before the insertion. It would be best if I can add `assert(false);` before or `throw std::logic_error{};`/`__builtin_unreachable();` instead of last `return` in comparator functor. I only can do it if there is corresponding logical guarantee. Can I do this?

Comment: If `Compare` doesn't conform to [Compare](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) concepts, then it's undefined behavior. In your `less` implementation, it's undefined behavior for `comp(a, a)`

Comment: @Danh the code of comparator is corrected now.

Comment: still not conform with Compare concepts

Comment: @Dahn In which part of them?

Comment: if `pl == &l` and `&l = &r`

Comment: @Danh You think `comp(a, a)` is possible somewhere into the implementation of `std::set`?

Comment: The standard said so

Comment: @Danh The question is: if I insert `m` (`m < r && l < m`) between `l` and `r` successive elements using hint to `r`, can I be sure, that only `comp(l, m)`, `comp(r, m)`, `comp(m, l)` and `comp(m, r)` invocations are possible?

Comment: The only requirement is that if the hint is good, the number of comparisons is constant. Nothing else.

Comment: @Danh If I have only unique elements and adjust `comp` before any operation, which uses it, are you sure, I can't rely on some evident expected behaviour?

Comment: @T.C. bad news =(.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the containers expect the comparison function to be consistent; i.e, that `comp(a,b)` gives the same answer every time.

Comment: @MarshallClow So, even using hint I can't even expect that there are only "local" `comp` operations performed. During insertion in the middle of 1000000-element container `c` it is possible `comp` of 500000 with 500-th or 1500-th element accidentally? Or even `comp(100000-th, 999998-th)` elements. It is counterintuitive.

Comment: The hint guarantees that if its inserted just before hint, then it will be amortized constant time, is that not enough?

Comment: @Surt Shure not. I want to totally expel comparisons between elements into container. They are not directly comparable, but indirectly are.